# How to retain previous Undoable Edit Listener When set editor kit mehtod is called

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, documentlistener

I have registered Undoable Edit Listener in JTextPane .

It works nice when editor kit remains  unchanged.

But When i am opening another  file  of different extension. I have to change the textpane editor kit .

Note: Actually textArea is an instance of JTextPane

```
   if(ext.equals(".txt")){
try{
   // textArea.setText(null);
textArea.setEditorKit(defaultkit);

    String read=reader.readLine();
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    int offset =0;
  //int test=0;
     while (read  !=null){
text.append(read);
text.append('\n');
read = reader.readLine();


    }
textArea.setText(text.toString());

}catch(IOException e ){}
//catch(BadLocationException e ){}

 }
 else{

     try {
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);    


 if(ext.equals(".rtf")){


 textArea.setEditorKit(ek);
 textArea.getEditorKit().read(fis, textArea.getDocument(), 0);


     }
```

I've found that when setEditorKit method is being called register document listener stop performing it's function .

When  I  register another undoable edit listner it won't work

```
textArea.setEditorKit(ek);
textArea.addUndoableEditListener(new MyListener());
```

Comment: `Actually textArea is an instance of JTextPane` - then why don't you call it that?

Comment: I used jTextArea first ; i named it 'textArea'  then i have to change the editor for styling purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and its solution

i was using new instance of document listener while registering another document listener

```
MyDocumentListener dl = new MyDocumentListener();
textArea.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(new MyDocumentListener());
```

instead i should use this every time:

```
textArea.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(dl);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have to change the textpane editor kit

No you don't.

You just use:

```
textPane.setText("");
```

to clear the data.

Of course if you do this the same listener would be used for both files. So you want to replace the edit listener every time you change the file anyway.

Comment: Styled Editor Kit is not useful for "rtf" content...that's why i have to change the editor kit .It just writes simple text in .rtf file

Comment: @M.H, in any case the simple solution is to just reset the listener when the editor kit is changed. The undo/redo should only apply to the new file not the old file.